# How to echo an image by a quantity in its adjacent cell?

Tags: php

I have the following data base

```
+---------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+  
|    id   |   award  |   image   |    type      |          description           |    qty    |  
+---------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+  
|    1    |  award 1 | award.jpg | award type 1 |   2010, 2011, 2013, 2014,      |      4    |  
+---------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+
```

My php code

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE type="award type 1"";
    $query_award =  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $result = '';
        $count = 0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_award)){
            $count++;
            $id = $row['id'];
            $award = $row['award'];
            $image = $row['image'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $qty = $row['qty'];


            $result .= "
                <div class='type'>" . $type . "</div>
                <div class='awards'>" . $image . "</div>
                <div class='details'>" .$award . " (" . $qty . "):" . $description . "</div>
            ";
}
?>
```

How would I make sure,when echoing `$result` it will echo the image 4 times or whatever value in the `qty` column.

Comment: I don't know how to and I did some searches but I couldn't find anything. It would appear simple enough thought

Comment: some comments downvoters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop. You would also need to start the counter at `1` as opposed to `0` because you're using `1 based` indexing.

```
$result .= "
    <div class='type'>". $type ."</div>
    <div class='awards'>";
        for($i = 1; $i < $row['qty']; $i++):
            $result .= $image;
        endfor;
$result .="
    </div>
    <div class='details'>" .$award . " (" . $qty . "):" . $description . "</div>
        ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)?

```
<?php
$img = "image.jpg";
$qty = 4;

echo str_repeat(sprintf('<div class="awards">%1$s</div>', $img), $qty);
?>
```

Your put this within your deprecated mysql_* code's while loop, between the invalid html code.